# Get user from User session jackrabbit

Tags: java, jackrabbit, jcr

I have created which is not part of admin group. Wanted to retrieve user object from logged-in user session.

Using admin created user:

```
org.apache.jackrabbit.api.security.user.User applicationUser  =
  accessController.createUser(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
```

Login with newly created user:

```
Session session = repository.login(
    new SimpleCredentials(userInstance.getUsername(),
    userInstance.getPassword().toCharArray()));
```

Trying to retrieve user object:

```
UserManager userManager = ((JackrabbitSession)adminSession).getUserManager(); 
User repoUser = (User) userManager.getAuthorizable(userName);
```

But `userManager` is null, since session created from user is not part of *admin group*.

Only way I find is to impersonate user session to admin and retrieve user object.

But is there any other way to retrieve `User` object without impersonation?

Using *Jackrabbit* 2.6.0 and *JCR* 2.0.

Thanks.

Comment: userManager shouldnt be null. If there is a problem then it should throw an exception.

Comment: Your comment is irrelevant. What I was looking for is any alternative and not userManager creation issue.

Comment: You're wrong, it's completely relevant. UserManager is the correct way to get a user. You clearly have a problem in your code which we can't see as you haven't shown all your code.

Comment: My problem is, in order to retrieve UserManager, user should be part of admin group or superuser. But one user wants to share some folder or document to another user(sharing through principal based acl), he should impersonate as admin user and set acl accordingly. I wanted to avoid impersonation.

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea. If a user should be able to grant permissions on a folder then they should be given the permissions to do that, not impersonate admin.

Comment: I agree. User has all access on a folder, he wants to share. But how could he can get UserManager(for getting another user principal) object?

Comment: try to change repository.xml by replacing simple.SimpleSecurityManager...

Answer (score 0):

try to change repository.xml by replacing simple.SimpleSecurityManager...,it works:

```html
<Security appName="Jackrabbit">
 
  <SecurityManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.DefaultSecurityManager" workspaceName="security">
   <!--
   workspace access:
   class: FQN of class implementing the WorkspaceAccessManager interface
   -->
   <!-- <WorkspaceAccessManager class="..."/> -->
   <!-- <param name="config" value="${rep.home}/security.xml"/> -->
  </SecurityManager>
  
  <AccessManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.DefaultAccessManager">
   <!-- <param name="config" value="${rep.home}/access.xml"/> -->
  </AccessManager>

  <LoginModule class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.authentication.DefaultLoginModule">
   <!--
     anonymous user name ('anonymous' is the default value)
    -->
   <param name="anonymousId" value="anonymous"/>
   <!--
     administrator user id (default value if param is missing is 'admin')
    -->
   <param name="adminId" value="admin"/>
  </LoginModule>
 </Security>
```